# Adding other columns Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, rdbms

I have to make a DBMS for Cars in Access. But I got a problem. In my previous question I got this code and it solved my first problem. But now I only get the columns `TotalPrijs`, `AutoNR` and `Klasse`. But I also need:  `Factuur.Dagen`, `Factuur.KlantNR` etc. I usually did this with the `SELECT` but now the code is more complicated and I don't know how to get it without getting a error.

This is my code.

```
SELECT 
SUM(A.TotaalPrijs) As TotaalPrijs,
A.AutoNR,
A.AutoKlasse
FROM
(SELECT Factuur.Dagen, Factuur.AutoNR AS carNR, autos.AutoNR, autos.Klasse AS AutoKlasse, Prijzen.Klasse, Prijzen.dag125KM, Prijzen.ExtraKM, (prijzen.dag125KM*Factuur.Dagen) AS MinPrijs, Factuur.FactuurNR, Factuur.KlantNR, Factuur.Begindatum, Factuur.Einddatum, Factuur.Borg, (((([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand])-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125))*[Prijzen]![ExtraKM])+([Prijzen]![dag125KM]*[Factuur]![Dagen])) AS TotaalPrijs, Gegevens.voorletters, Gegevens.tussenvoegsel, Gegevens.achternaam, Gegevens.straatnaam, Gegevens.huisNR, Gegevens.Postcode, Gegevens.rekeningNR, Gegevens.Plaats, (([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand])-Dagen*125) AS KMteVEEL
        FROM autos, Factuur, Prijzen, Gegevens
        WHERE (((Factuur.AutoNR)=Autos.AutoNR) And ((autos.Klasse)=Prijzen.Klasse) And ((Factuur.KlantNR)=Gegevens.KlantNR))
) AS A
GROUP BY 
    A.AutoNR, A.AutoKlasse
```

how to add the `Factuur.Dagen` and `Factuur.KlantNR` and my other columns?

Comment: In a group of say one `AutoNR= "1"` and `AutoKlasse="2"` , how many `Dagen` values are qualified??

Comment: Dagen is just a value in the table Factuur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have grouped data in hand, and your `SELECT` expects only one of it... SOmehow you have take out one logical value.

This is why we use `AGGREGATE` function. Just like `SUM()` did an addition of all `TotaalPrijs` in your grouped data.. Taking a `MAX(Dagen)` would one value from that group.

```
SELECT 
SUM(A.TotaalPrijs) As TotaalPrijs,
A.AutoNR,
A.AutoKlasse,
MAX(Factuur.Dagen) -- < you need just this..!
```

**OR** add this column to your grouping condition as well!

```
GROUP BY A.AutoNR, A.AutoKlasse,Factuur.Dagen
```

Comment: Thanks! but that just worked for 1 column :( I need to add another few columns from the tables: Gegevens, Factuur, Autos and Prijzen. Any solution I can get more than just 1?

Comment: Even logically you cannot pick some random from the group. SO, add aggregate function to all your columns.!!!

Comment: Thanks you solved the issue! Will post my verry last question now in another post.